# What is the proper way to initialize an external framework in an Aurelia app

Tags: aurelia

I want to know if this is the Aurelia way to initialize a framework.
I am using foundation 6 and have made an override which is working fine

Override:

```
{
    "main": "dist/foundation",
    "files": ["dist", "assets", "js", "scss"],
    "shim": {
    "dist/foundation": {
        "deps": "jQuery",
            "exports": "Foundation"
    }
  },
    "dependencies": {
    "jQuery": "github:components/jquery"
  }
}
```

In my main.ts I modified the below code adding

```
.then(a=> {
//initialize framework
        $(document).foundation();
})
```

Full main.ts code

```
import 'foundation';
import {Aurelia} from 'aurelia-framework';


export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging();

  //Uncomment the line below to enable animation.
  aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-animator-css');

  //Anyone wanting to use HTMLImports to load views, will need to install the following plugin.
  //aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-html-import-template-loader')

  aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot())
      .then(a => {
        //initialize framework
        $(document).foundation();
      });
}
```

This works but is it the proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The excellent Aureila manual documents the various ways you can organize your application's configuration and startup.  It sounds to me like you might want to consider creating a "Feature Module".

Create a folder called "foundation" with an index.js file:

```
export function configure(config) {
  $(document).foundation();      
}
```

Then you can enable your feature from the app configuration:

```
export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .feature('foundation');

  aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot());
}
```

More information in the [App Configuration and Startup](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/app-configuration-and-startup) chapter.